# Flashlight on lockscreen on Galaxy S5

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-5, camera-flash

I am soon going on a field trip and would like to give my friends the ability to use the flash light from the phone without giving them the pattern to unlock the phone. Is that possible to add the flashlight/torch to the locked screen just like the camera?

I have a Galaxy S5 with Android 4.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your camera shortcut is on in the lockscreen. Open the camera from the lockscreen, drag your flash setting to the top from the camera settings and make sure it is on. Now all you have to do is open the camera shortcut and click video and your light will stay on. It will also record video while it's on but this is the only way to turn on your flashlight from the lockscreen.

Answer (score 1):

Not without a different ROM but you may be able to add one to the notification area. Try [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.notificationToggle), I don't know how well (if at all) it works on the S5 but it's worth a shot.

Comment: I recommend this. I use it on an S3, so a S5 should have no trouble.

Comment: Thanks, but after watching the video and reading the description, I don't see how this gives me what I want. -- As I said, I want to be able to turn on the flashlight without unlocking the device. But seems like a nice app anyway.

Comment: @Martin Can you not put a flash light toggle in the status bar then the person who needs the light can swipe the bar down and use the toggle?

Comment: @DanielStewart The phone is about a week old so I don't know what you mean. I'm not sure what you mean by "status bar".

Comment: The status bar is the pull-down bar at the top of the screen where you can access quick toggles and view notifications.

Answer (score 0):

On the last models of Samsung was easy! Just press the volume key and the flashlight is turning on! (of course you should first to approve this in settings:) When you want to stop it just press the volume down! I have Xcover 1 and 2, I used it a lot, it is easy and good option but sometimes the flashlight was turned on in my pocket of my carhartt jeans and the battery finished very quick. So in settings you can make the flashlight to work only 1-2min. and to stop automatically. I bought S5 Active few days ago and I am very angry that the phone has no same option!!! I see one decision but. To upload a Torch APP and then to switch on this APP with functional extra key, which is over the volume key.

Answer (score 0):

The S5 Lollipop update now has the flashlight available as a notification sort cut, you can add it to the list of 'quick settings' and just use it that way now. Tested as of today 25.02.2015.0

Comment: This doesnot answer the question. The OP has mentioned that he has a kitkat device and you have provided a lollipop answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [CM Locker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cmcm.locker) by Cheetah Mobile. This is an iOS based Locker. Give CM Locker a try!

Comment: You may want to be careful about recommending Cheetah apps based on a new report out about Cheetah, and Google Play actions against them. See this: [https://www.xda-developers.com/google-bans-600-apps-play-store/](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-bans-600-apps-play-store/).

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the flashlight by holding both **volume keys** with [Torchie - Volume Button Torch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.blogspot.anselmbros.torchie) app.

Or **shake** your phone to turn on the flashlight with [Shake Flashlight](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidrocker.shakeflashlight) app.

---

Source: [5 Quick Ways to Turn on the Flashlight on Your Android Device](https://www.maketecheasier.com/turn-on-flashlight-android/)